# Headset issues when connecting to my MacBook Pro Retina 13

Tags: macbook, headset

My MacBook Pro Retina (running Sierra) is connected by USB to my Jabra 9400 headset which cuts out in the middle of GotoMeeting calls for 1-2 seconds at a time... seems random, but completely unacceptable.  Any ideas on how to fix this mystery?